# MySQL Name Profit with date range

Tags: mysql

**MySQL:**

My table

```
Name | Profit | Date
Cap  | 20     | 2014-04-19 08:52:00
Cap  | 15     | 2014-04-19 07:52:00
Cup  | 25     | 2014-04-19 07:55:00
Cup  | 22     | 2014-04-18 13:05:30
```

**I want Date Range 2014-04-19 00:00:00 TO 2014-04-19 23:59:59:**

*Result example:*

```
Name| Profit
Cap | 35
Cup | 25
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, you should try to show more examples of what you have tried to get the desired output. That is probably why someone down voted your question (it was not me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select name, sum(profit)
from yourtable
WHERE 
date >= '2014-04-19 00:00:00' 
AND 
date <  '2014-04-19 23:59:59'
group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select Name,sum(Profit)
from table1
WHERE 
Date >='2014-04-19 00:00:00' 
AND 
Date < '2014-04-19 23:59:59'
group by name
```

## [**Working Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc131/1)